# String.valueOf() behavior with char[] in List<char[]>

Tags: java, collections

I was working with `char[]` and `Collection` with the below code :-

```
    char[] ch = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    List<char[]> chList = new ArrayList<char[]>();
    chList.add(new char[]{'d','e','f'});
    chList.add(new char[]{'g','h','i'});
    String chSt = String.valueOf(ch);
    String chListSt = chList.toString(); 
    System.out.println(chSt);  // outputs  abc
    System.out.println(chListSt); // outputs [[C@8288f50b, [C@b6d2b94b] instead [def, ghi]
```

Now what I observed above is :-

```
    String chSt = String.valueOf(ch);
```

I know the above code behaviour is correct for `char[]` in `String.valueOf()`, so for the above code `abc` is printed. Now consider the next line.

```
    String chListSt = chList.toString();
```

Also for the above code I know the `toString()` for `List` is defined in `AbstractList` and in the code of this overriden `toString()` I found `buffer.append(next);` which calls `String.valueOf()` method on the `char[]` which corresponds to `next` here.

So it should also print like `[def, ghi]`, as in the direct case with `char[]` in the line `String chSt = (String.valueOf(ch));`

Why is this change in behaviour is there in both the cases while same method `String.valueOf()` is called on the `char[]`?

Comment: In first case you are printing char[] , in 2nd you are printing List of <char[]>

Comment: @JishnuPrathap its `List` of `char[]` not `String`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're seeing the difference of calling different overloads of `String.valueOf`. Here's a simpler example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] chars = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(chars));  // abc
        Object object = chars;
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(object));  // [C@...
    }
}
```

The call you've found in `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` is just going to call `String.valueOf(Object)` - which then calls `toString()` on the array (after checking the reference isn't null). Arrays don't override `toString` in Java, hence the output you're getting.

Comment: so why doesn't the `String.valueOf(chars)` got called in my case ? Shouldn't it be checked at runtime  that `object` is actually `char[]`?

Comment: @AnkitNigam: Because the code calling `String.valueOf` doesn't know that the argument is a `char[]`. Don't forget that overload resolution is determined at compile-time.

Comment: is something related to type erasure also happens here?

Comment: @AnkitNigam: Not really. The same thing would happen in C#, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Code `String chListSt = chList.toString();` simply called toString() implementation of List. List implementation calls toString() implementation on the elements.

Your current list has array objects in the list as an elements, so you are getting an array.toString() representation on the console which results hexadecimal code printed for char[].

> Instead of char[] try to save string in the array. It will have same performance and results will be readable.

Comment: List implementation `toString()` calls `String.valueOf(obj)`  on each `obj`

Comment: True Ankit, and `String.valueOf(obj)` calls `toString()` implementation internally. Check the `valueOf()` method of String.

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] ch = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```

The above one is a literal and hence `valueof()` method gives it value.

```
chList.add(new char[]{'d','e','f'});
chList.add(new char[]{'g','h','i'});
```

These lists have objects stored in them as a result you are getting their hashcodes...